# Log the nth-child number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I log the the nth-child number of an element in a container using jQuery. Thanks in advance.

```js
$('.wrapper p').on('click', function() {
  //log the nth-child number of the clicked element
  console.log($(this).nth-child())
})
```

```css
p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
  <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Example: Say you pressed the `<p>` tag with content second then the log would be 2 because the `<p>` tag is found in the second position of the container.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @Rajesh so say you pressed the p tag with content second then the log would be 2 because the p tag is found in the second position of the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Array.from to convert NodeList to Array of Elements and use `indexOf` to get index of child

```js
$('.wrapper p').on('click', function() {
  const allElements = $('.wrapper p');
  const index = Array.from(allElements).indexOf(this) + 1
  console.log(index)
})
```

```css
p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
  <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Comment: nice i will accept answer when it allows me

Answer (score 1):

This whole thing can be two lines (or one if you want to be creative) inside the event handler. OR leverage the jQuery index function for super simple.

First, simple example just logs index.

More complex shows some results.

Here I added some extra to handle multiple target groups, and show some results with some icky borders for clarity.

I increased the "index" for these to start from 1; but they really start from 0.

Simple, no results details:

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'p', function(event) {
  const index = $(this).index() + 1;
  console.log(index);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
  <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Expanded for more details

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'p', function(event) {
  /* two lines
    const targetGroupElements = $(event.delegateTarget).find('p');
    const index = targetGroupElements.index(this) + 1;
  */
  /* one line */
  //const index = $(event.delegateTarget).find('p').index(this) + 1;
  // leverage jQuery .index()
  const index = $(this).index() +1;
  // just to show results:
  const rt = $('<div/>');
  const r = $('#results').html("Last clicked:");
  r.append(rt.clone().html("Index:" + index));
  r.append(rt.clone().html("Text:" + $(this).text()));
  r.append(rt.clone().html("Group Index:" + $(event.delegateTarget).index()));
  r.append(rt.clone().html("GroupName:" + $(event.delegateTarget).data("group")));
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid pink 1px;
}

#results {
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

#results div {
  border: solid cyan 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" data-group="first">
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
  <p>third</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" data-group="twos">
  <p>first-2</p>
  <p>second - 2</p>
  <p>third - 2</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper" data-group="three">
  <p>first off</p>
  <p>second off</p>
  <p>thirdly</p>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery `index` method too.

```
$('.wrapper p').on('click', function() {
   console.log($('.wrapper p').index(this))
})
```